# WPF adorners vs custom adorners?

Tags: wpf, adorner, adornerlayer

I would like to create an diagram editor and there is a requirement to move and resize huge amount of items.

And I also I have heard that default WPF adorners are slow.

What is the best way and recommendations to make responsive adorers layer?
Custom or based on the WPF built-in adorners?
As far as I know expression blend is also using its own adorners implementation.

For me the performance is more important than implementation time.

Thanks.

Comment: it's not clear why do you want to use adorners at all?
Besides it is a common case when there are a number of adorner layers in WPF window: by defaul one layer has window, each ScrollPresenter also bring new adorner layer

Comment: I heard that default adorners are slow.

Comment: Well I've used adorners, even created a set of derived classes, they worked fine for me, but i had only few of them visible at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the real implementation an testing:
If you have a lot of complex controls and performance meters than it's better to use OnRender() method.  Preview events are working fine to find out that you about to interact with a fake adorners, but it's an extra work.